# Why does PyInstaller throw a Broken Pipe Error?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, broken-pipe

all!

I wrote a python script that imports PySimpleGui and OS. I put the 3 py's into my folder and ran `pyinstaller --onefile -w processnc.py` . At first it ran fine and I got my executable, which worked fine, but had some complications and I ended up losing it. Now I tried running it again but it throws a Broken Pipe Error even if I try running it in a different directory using only the 3 files.

Any tips?

Command output:

```
22 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.4.1
22 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
27 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.19.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
27 INFO: wrote /home/aaron/processnc.spec
28 INFO: UPX is not available.
29 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/aaron/Documents/SistemasTecnologias4.0']
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 79, in <module>
    import os
  File "/home/aaron/Documents/SistemasTecnologias4.0/os.py", line 48, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import _get_hub_noargs as get_hub
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py", line 337, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py", line 266, in call
    ok, output = loads(b64decode(self._read_handle.readline()))
EOFError: EOF read where object expected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 179, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 60, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 962, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 884, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/aaron/processnc.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 376, in __init__
    self.hookspath += discover_hook_directories()
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py", line 368, in wrapped
    return call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py", line 337, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py", line 232, in __exit__
    self._write_handle.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```